# how to filter something within a category

Tags: laravel

in laravel I wanted to do something about this regeneration,
I choose a category in request mode and then I wanted to filter within the category only packages with that request

for example

```
$pacotes = pacotes:orderBy('pacote_preco', $order)
                        ->whereDate('pacote_validade', '>', Carbon::now())
                        ->with('imagens')
                        ->where('pacote_categoria', $categoria)
                        ->where('pacote_descricao', 'like', "%" . $pesquisar . "%"
                        ->orWhere('pacote_titulo', 'like', "%" . $pesquisar . "%"
                        ->paginate(12);
```

but it shows all the packages I have with this request search value, and I would like to appeal to those with this value within the selected category

Comment: You have errors in your code, also three `and`ed and one `or`ed condition which will probably not give your what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If we used `toSql()` on your query it will come out like this:

```
select * from `pacotes:` 
where date(`pacote_validade`) > ? and `pacote_categoria` = ? and `pacote_descricao` like ? 
or `pacote_titulo` like ? order by `pacote_preco` desc
```

Now this query's syntax is correct but its `where` logic is broken.

Your last condition will always be true because you didn't group your conditions properly  and it will get you false results.

Using [`where Closure`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#parameter-grouping) will prevent any erroneous results

```
pacotes::orderBy('pacote_preco', $order)
                    ->whereDate('pacote_validade', '>', Carbon::now())
                    ->with('imagens')
                    ->where('pacote_categoria', $categoria)
                    ->where(function ($query) {
                          $query->where('pacote_descricao', 'like', "%" . $pesquisar . "%")
                          ->orWhere('pacote_titulo', 'like', "%" . $pesquisar . "%");
                    })
                    ->paginate(12);
```

---

Using toSql() again we can see the we addded an openning and closing brackets to the query which should get you the desired results.

```
select * from `goods` 
where date(`pacote_validade`) > ? and `pacote_categoria` = ? 
and (`pacote_descricao` like ? or `pacote_titulo` like ?) 
order by `pacote_preco` desc
```